# Vitest test failed caused by ejs module in library

Tags: reactjs, vite, vitest

```js
fe-vite:test: ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Failed Suites 1 ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
fe-vite:test:
fe-vite:test: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
fe-vite:test:  ❯ Object.compileFunction ../../../../../../../node:vm:360:18
fe-vite:test: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
fe-vite:test:  ❯ Object.compileFunction ../../../../../../../node:vm:360:18
fe-vite:test:  ❯ Object.<anonymous> ../../node_modules/react-addressfinder/dist/WidgetInput.js:7:1
fe-vite:test:  ❯ Object.<anonymous> ../../node_modules/react-addressfinder/dist/index.js:5:50
fe-vite:test:  ❯ ../../../../../../../async C:/Users//work//packages/ui/src/form/AddressFinder/index.tsx:8:31        fe-vite:test:  ❯ ../../../../../../../async C:/Users//work//packages/ui/src/index.tsx:1:256
fe-vite:test:  ❯ ../../../../../../../async C:/Users//work//apps/fe-vite/src/components/application/ApplicationContinueButton.tsx:4:31fe-vite:test:  ❯ ../../../../../../../async C:/Users//work//apps/fe-vite/src/pages/application/Borrowers.tsx:8:31    
fe-vite:test:  ❯ ../../../../../../../async C:/Users//work//apps/fe-vite/src/test/application/Borrowers.test.tsx:6:31
```

The test with vitest keep failed.
I think is module issue.
One library I am using, react-addressfinder, require a css file, and my vite app is esm based.
If I remove the line below, require("./widget.css"),
The test works well.

Is there any way to use both esm and cjs for vitest?
There is no probelm when just running apps.

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var tslib_1 = require("tslib");
var react_1 = (0, tslib_1.__importStar)(require("react"));
var constants_1 = require("./constants");
var helpers_1 = require("./helpers");
require("./widget.css");
```